# Column cannot be found in crystal reports from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports

Whats wrong with my code? Whenever  I run this, I get the error 'ResidentID' cannot be found.
But in my gridview there is this column ResidentID..

```
 var frmReportViewer = new frmReportViewer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("No");
            dt.Columns.Add("ResidentID");

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in this.dgrAdvancedSearch.Rows)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells["No"].Value, dr.Cells["ResidentID"].Value);
            }

            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptDoc = default(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument);

            rptDoc = new crptAdvancedSearch();
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);

            frmReportViewer.crvAdvancedSearch.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            frmReportViewer.ShowDialog();
            frmReportViewer.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you sure with your database connections ?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing worng with the DB connections.. its just when I try to open Report Viewer, the error occurs.

Comment: can you show us your datagridview?